# Mac Mini Video out

Tags: display, mac-mini, screen

I recently aquired a Mac Mini 1.42ghz but I get no video out. It chimes on and everything but nothing on the monitor. optical drive seems t work

Comment: Can you be a little more specific to the types of outputs you are trying? Does the monitor work with other computers? Is everything plugged together tightly and securely? Enter you serial number here: http://support.apple.com/specs/ and let us know the year so we can maybe help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with de_an777. We could use more info. However, if you think the computer is running, you might want to try to screen share from another system, or connect via Firewire Target mode, and run some disk checks. If you can screenshare, you might want to try accessing the monitor preference on the mini, and changing the setting way down (640 x 480) to see if that works.

I dont know if this works anymore (showing my age), but if you try to reset the PRAM - this can reset the monitor settings. This will cause late life arthritis but you restart the mini - then when you hear the chime - press CMD, OPT/ALT, P and R at the same time, and hold them until the chime sounds for 3 or 4 times.... Let go, and see what happens.